# jquery selector populate text input with attribute value

Tags: jquery, anchor, selector

I have 40 anchor tags as such and in a form a hidden field with an id of image

```
<a name="select_image" id="x">
<img ...> 
</a>
```

I want to on image click populate the image text input with the attribute value.

```
$('a[name=select_image]').click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$("#image").val(id);
$('#browse').modal('hide');
});
```

the modal doesnt dismiss so I guess there is something wrong with the selector?

***EDIT:***
Just realised all of the anchor tags are loaded via jquery which si why it doesnt work. I believe there is a way to do this but I cant remember how.

Comment: It's probably that underscore throwing things off - surround it in double quotes: `$('a[name="select_image"]')`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this didnt solve it, however i just realised something, see update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the anchor tags are generated dynamically, you need to do a click event delegation to the dynamically created element:

```
  $(document).on('click','a[name=select_image]',function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#image").val(id);
    $('#browse').modal('hide');
    });
```

Comment: updated the solution with another approach, see if that works.